# How to Add Edit / Remove button in datatable at laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-4, datatable, laravel-routing

I used laravel 4.2 billam Server side Datatable, and now it' works. But I can't add Edit and Remove Button in this datatable.

View page :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var oTable;
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#tasks').dataTable( {
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "{{ URL::to('/task') }}"
    });
});
```

Route :

```
Route::get('/task',function(){
$posts = Campaigns::select(array('title','created_at','status'));
 return Datatables::of($posts)
 ->make();
});
```

Now how can I add Delete and edit button ? I am follow there documentation from [here](https://github.com/bllim/laravel4-datatables-package)  that not works for me.

Documented Example 2: Adding and editing columns

```
->add_column('operations', '<a href="{{ URL::route( \'admin.post\', array( \'edit\',$id )) }}">edit</a>
                <a href="{{ URL::route( \'admin.post\', array( \'delete\',$id )) }}">delete</a>
            ')
->edit_column('status', '{{ $status ? 'Active' : 'Passive' }}')
->edit_column('ownername', function($row) {
    return "The author of this post is {$row->ownername}";
})
```

But how can I use blade structured code in route or controller? it's make little confusion..

Comment: Why doesn't the linked documentation work for you?

Comment: @TZHX, This code working without edit & remove button.. but my question is how to add edit button..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a link to a datatables column from the controller you can do something like this:

```
->addColumn('actions', function ($data) {
                return "<a class='btn btn-xs btn-success' href='/management/members/$data->id/view'>View</a>";
            })
```

$data is the query after the datatables wrapper. So in conecpt of the controller method, this will be used similar to this:

```
/**
 * Members list data.
 *
 * @param Datatables $datatables
 * @param MemberRepository $repository
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function getIndexData(Datatables $datatables, MemberRepository $repository)
{
    $members = $repository->getMemberListForManagement();


    return $datatables->usingQueryBuilder($members)
        ->editColumn('created_at', function ($data) {
            return date('d F Y', strtotime($data->created_at));
        })
        ->editColumn('is_banned',
            '@if($is_banned)
                Yes
            @else
                No
            @endif')
        ->addColumn('actions', function ($data) {
            return "<a class='btn btn-xs btn-success' href='/management/members/$data->id/view'>View</a>";
        })
        ->removeColumn('id')
        ->make(true);
}
```